# Trying to access key in dictionary: "Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : Array<String>]' with an index of type 'Int'"

Tags: swift, dictionary

What I'm trying to do is generate a random number between 1 and 52 (`firstRandomNumber`), then set `dictionaryTest` to be equal to the key at the corresponding index in the dictionary.

For instance, if the `firstRandomNumber` generated happens to be `2`, `dictionaryTest` should be equal to the key at `deckDictionary[2]`, which is `"card2"`.

```
var deckDictionary = [
        "card1": ["rank","suit"],
        "card2": ["rank","suit"],
        "card3": ["rank","suit"],
        "card4": ["rank","suit"],
        "card5": ["rank","suit"],
        ////... clipped for brevity
        "card52": ["rank","suit"],
]

let firstRandomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(52))+1
let dictionaryTest = deckDictionary[firstRandomNumber]
print(dictionaryTest)
```

When I try to do this however, setting `dictionaryTest` gives me the following error:

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : Array]' with an index of type 'Int'

I'm not sure what this means, is it because the "card2" key/string contains an array itself?

Comment: This is the *same code* and the *same error message* as in your previous question (only "deckArray" has been renamed to "deckDictionary").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because keys in your deckDictionary are of type String, and you are trying to access the element in deckDictionary using int key. 
You can probably do something like this:

```
let firstRandomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(52))+1
let key = "card\(firstRandomNumber)"
let dictionaryTest = deckDictionary[key]
```